# What CSS Property / HTML element is giving this vertical line effect?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the bootstrap ***'Agency'*** template found [here](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/), on the *about* section there is a vertical line connecting all of the circle images. I have been looking however I cannot find the style rule or html element which is giving this affect. 
Can anyone tell me what is doing this, so I can then modify it (e.g. line length)?

[image]

Comment: The `::before` pseudo-element on the `<ul class="timeline">` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a `ul` element (with the class `timeline`) styled as follows:

```
.timeline:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 40px;
    width: 2px;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Also, as pointed out by @Vucko:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.timeline:before {
    left: 50%;
}
```

Each point in the timeline is an `li` (the right hand side `li`s are just given a different class `timeline-inverted`).

Nice Question.

Comment: With `left:50%` on `(min-width: 768px)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really helpful, but how would I go about changing the height of the line, would it just be to reduce the margin top / bottom of the li?

Comment: @TobyCannon Are you familiar with the developer console included in major web browsers? Accessible via the F12 key. You can inspect HTML elements on any web page using this developer console and editing the properties within your browser. They will reset any time you refresh the page.

Comment: @TobyCannon the line goes to the last `li` element. You could change it by changing the `top` property.

Answer (score 0):

On the `ul` with `class="timeline"` there is a `::before` object created in css that's given a gray background color to create that line.

```
.timeline:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 40px;
    width: 2px;
    margin-left: -1.5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what I would do: create a div that's only 1px in width and however long you want in height, give it a background color, and you will end up with a vertical line.

Comment: That's not what this question is asking.